# How to pass parameter to javascript from Django template while using for loop

Tags: javascript, django

I am creating a quiz application using django.
I am facing a problem in sending paramter to my javascript function from django template.

Html Code.

```
{% for qts in page %}

<input type="button" id ="btn-1" name="grp" value="{{qts.opt1}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3" onclick = "check(this,{{qts.answer}})">
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function check(btn,answer) {
   var user_ans_id = btn.id;
   var user_ans = document.getElementById(user_ans_id).value;
   console.log(answer);
}
```

Is there any other solution.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is not working? Are you sure `qts` has an `opt1`? How does the *rendered* output looks like?

Comment: Willem onclick = "check(this,{{qts.answer}}) here is the problem.Please help

Comment: but you simnply do not tell *what* the problem is. What is not working, what is the HTTP response (so the *rendered* version*). How does the view looks like? What is the function supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry Willem. I am getting this javascipt error in console due to {{qts.answer}} Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and cleaner way of achieving the desired output can be implemented as follows using jquery

```
    {% for qts in page %}
    <input type="button" value="{{qts.opt1}}" class="quest-btn" data-answer="{{qts.answer}}" />
    {% endfor %}
    <script>
        $(".quest-btn").click((e) => {
            const targetElement = e.target;
            console.log(
                targetElement.dataset.answer,
                targetElement.value
            );
        });
    </script>
```

In the about code quest-class is just a dummy class to attach click event listener to multiple button you can use any common class in buttons.

to know more about jquery click event listener [check this out](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

for more info about data-attributes [check this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp)

Comment: I wanted {{qts.answer}} to be hidden

Comment: @charanjeetsingh check the updated answer, you should  mention 'I wanted {{qts.answer}} to be hidden' in querstion.